# how to start AWS SAM using a dockerfile

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to build two docker containers inspired by [Containerizing Serverless APIs](https://itnext.io/containerizing-serverless-apis-d69fa3e6b9c2). I want to run my my API and DynamoDB locally in two different containers as specified by my `Dockerfile` (for API) and `localstack` as (specified in docker-compose.yml`) for my local DynamoDB. These files are shared below.

*It exits after building the container for my API as evidenced by the logs below.*

```
Successfully built e0798a6833ce
Successfully tagged hafiz/hafiz_aws_api_gateway:latest
Starting dynamodb_localstack ... done
Recreating hafiz_aws_api_gateway ... done
Attaching to dynamodb_localstack, hafiz_aws_api_gateway
dynamodb_localstack | Starting mock DynamoDB (http port 8000)...
dynamodb_localstack | Ready.
dynamodb_localstack | (. .venv/bin/activate; exec bin/localstack start)
dynamodb_localstack | Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
dynamodb_localstack | Starting mock DynamoDB (http port 8000)...
dynamodb_localstack | Ready.
dynamodb_localstack | (. .venv/bin/activate; exec bin/localstack start)
dynamodb_localstack | Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
dynamodb_localstack | Starting mock DynamoDB (http port 8000)...
dynamodb_localstack | Ready.
dynamodb_localstack | 2019-04-16 05:01:01,975 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
dynamodb_localstack | 2019-04-16 05:01:01,977 INFO supervisord started with pid 12
hafiz_aws_api_gateway | sam_local_start_api.sh: 1: sam_local_start_api.sh: sam: not found
hafiz_aws_api_gateway exited with code 127
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
# builds the api container and sets up the localstack container to run
services:
  api:
    build: .
    image: hafiz/hafiz_aws_api_gateway
    depends_on:
      - localstack
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    container_name: hafiz_aws_api_gateway
    # these are the environment variables that are used in the api
    environment:
      AWS_ENDPOINT: 'http://dynamodb_localstack:8000' # localstack container host for dynamodb
      AWS_REGION: 'localhost'
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'fake-access-key-id'
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'fake-secret-key'
      AWS_TABLE_NAME: 'hafizItemTable'

  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:8000' # using port 8000 to be consistent with dynamodb local jar
      - '8080:8080' # the localstack admin portal
    container_name: dynamodb_localstack
    environment:
      SERVICES: dynamodb:8000
      DATA_DIR: '/tmp/localstack/data'
```

Here is my `dockerfile`

```
# use this dockerfile to build an image for this api

FROM node:8.10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["sh", "sam_local_start-api.sh"
```

My package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
    "seed": "node ./seed/runner.js",
    "start": "sam local start-api",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
...
```

My question is how can I specify CMD command in my docker file that will trigger a AWS SAM CLI Command:

```
sam local start-api
```

or if there is a better way of starting the script?

Comment: `sam` tool is installed on container  ? `sam: not found`

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/run-aws-lambda-functions-locally-on-windows-machin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CMD ["sh", "sam_local_start.sh"]
```

change to :

```
CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

It will trigger run command: `sam local start-api` on container terminal which it define in `package.json`

Make sure `sam` tool is installed already in container first.